# How does Lucene combine fields and boosting values to generate a score?

Tags: boost, lucene, scoring

I followed how Lucene scores a document in this link:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html

but how does Lucene deal with multiple fields and field boosts?  For example, if I have two fields: f1 and f2 and their corresponding field boosts: b1 and b2, would the final score be:

```
final score = b1*cosine_similarity(f1) + b2*cosine_similarity(f2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

cosine-similarity is a function of two parameters. First is the query and the second is the document.

In your case you probably have a boolean query which contains clauses for these two fields. For example, "f1: text OR f2: text". If you look at the scoring formula:

```
score(q, d) = coord(q,d) * queryNorm(q) * sum[tf(t in d) * idf(t)^2 * t.getBoost() * norm(t,d)]
```

you see there is an element norm(t, d). This function encapsulates boosts and length factors:

```
norm(t,d) = doc.getBoost() * lengthNorm * prod[f.getBoost()]
```

And that f.getBoost() is the boost of the corresponding field.

To summarise it is the simplified score of the query above (suppose tf = 1 and idf = 1/2 for both terms and all boosts other than field boosts are equal to 1):

```
score("f1: text OR f2: text", "{f1: '... text ...', f2: '... text ...'") = coordAndQueryNormPart * (1 * 1/4 * 1 * f1boost + 1 * 1/4 * 1 * f2boost)
```

UPD:

I wrote an example which might be helpful. Lucene index here contains two equal documents, but in the first document "f1" field is boosted:

```
    Directory dir = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);

    float field1Boost = 2.0f;

    Document doc = new Document();
    Field f1 = new Field("f1", "field text", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS);
    f1.setBoost(field1Boost);
    doc.add(f1);
    doc.add(new Field("f2", "another text", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
    writer.addDocument(doc);


    doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("f1", "field text", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
    doc.add(new Field("f2", "another text", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.commit();

    writer.close();

    IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(dir);

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "f1", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
    Query query = parser.parse("f1: text OR f2: text");
    TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 2);

    float score1 = docs.scoreDocs[0].score;
    float score2 = docs.scoreDocs[1].score;

    float score1check = 0.26274973154067993f * field1Boost + 0.26274973154067993f;
    float score2check = 0.26274973154067993f + 0.26274973154067993f;

    if (Math.abs(score1 - score1check) > 0.00001) throw new RuntimeException();
    if (Math.abs(score2 - score2check) > 0.00001) throw new RuntimeException();

    System.out.println("Score 1 = " + score1 + " ; score 2 = " + score2);
```